# Node-Webkit - Starting Maximized

Tags: node-webkit, maximize-window

I don't want a fullscreen application, but I would like to start a Node-Webkit application maximized. Can this be done? I am guessing its something to do with package.json, but can't seem to find what needs to be done.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't think the manifest has an option to do that. Instead, call nw's `Window.maximize()` on startup. Something like:

```
// Load native UI library
var ngui = require('nw.gui');

// Get the current window
var nwin = ngui.Window.get();
```

Sometime later, in `onload` or some other point where you're ready to show the window:

```
onload = function() {
    nwin.show();
    nwin.maximize();
}
```

This is described in the [node-webkit wiki](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Window). I don't think you can call maximize before showing the main window though (if it's hidden in manifest), but I haven't really dug into it.

You may want to consider saving the window position, from a UX standpoint. The wiki has an example for doing this.