# Set max_width , max_height 100% for Manifest nwjs

Tags: package.json, nwjs

I want to set with and height for my app to 1400 and 800  **If it is possible**  but if a Screen is smaller than 1400 or 800 , app opens full size  **Not Full Screen** 
I mean i want some thin like this:

```
"window": {
    "title": "My App",
    "toolbar": false,
    "min_width": 1400,
    "min_height": 800,
    "max_width": 100%,
    "max_height": 100%,  
}
```

I know i can set `fullscreen : true`

But i want some thing like above or something like this `fullsize : true`

Thanks

Comment: Probably looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423790/node-webkit-starting-maximized

Comment: @AdamK , Not Completely , But that was good, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty simple if you have a look at the documentation http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Screen/

```
Screen.Init() //initiate the screen
var screens = Screen.screens //get all screens. you may have more then one monitor....
var work_area = screens[0]. work_area //get the work area of the screen
var max_width = work_area.width //get the max width
var max_height = work_area.height //get the max height
//check if fullscreen should be entered
if(max_height < 800 || max-wdith < 1400){
     var win = nw.Window.get();
     win.enterFullscreen()
}
```

You basically check on startup if you have the screenwidth. If not you go to fullscreen. I think you could also us https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_display to get max-width and max-height